# Any idea how i can make radial corners on a clip path polygon

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create multiple boxes, I have tried clip-path: polygon only to create the design, I've also been searching for a minute, but couldn't come up with anything that works. Any ideas?

I tried this:

```
width: 12vh;
height: 7vh;
border-radius: 2vh;
clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

here is how i would like it to look
[image]

Comment: U can use this tool to generate clip-path [link](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Comment: can't make it rounded there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a nice little hack that works for you:

- tilt the parent container of a child element to the right with `transform: skew(...)`
- give the parent container a `border-radius` that meets you requirements
- tilt the child element back again to make its content stand upright.

**snippet**

```css
.parent {
    /* tilt the parent container to the right */
    transform: skew(-20deg); /* negative degrees */
    border-radius: 2vh 2.5vh;
}
.child {
    /* counteract the parent container tilt,
       making child upright again */
    transform: skew(20deg) /* positive degrees */
}

/* Just eye-candy below */
.parent {
    width: 12vh; height: 7vh; margin: 5rem auto;
    
    background-color: Black;
    color: White;
    
    /* Easy center an element!! */
    display: grid; place-items: center;
}
.child { font-size: 1.75vh }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">kid</div>
</div>
```